# Find an Email Address On a Web Page Using a Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find email addresses within a URL address using the findall() function in a RegEx. This is my desired outcome (being typed into shell):

```
>>>from urllib.request import urlopen
>>>url = 'http://www.cdm.depaul.edu'
>>>content = urlopen(url).read().decode()
>>>emails(content)
>>>{'advising@cdm depaul.edu' , 'wwwfeedback@cdm.depaul.edu' ,
admission@cdm.depaul.edu' , 'webmaster@cdm.depaul.edu' }
```

this is my code:

```
def emails(doc):
    return findall('[\d]*@[\d]+', don't know what to set second argument as)
```

I know it's simple, but I can't figure out what my second argument is suppose to be, so I keep getting an empty list returned. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Well, I appreciate the clarity, thank you... I think

Comment: Hehe. You're welcome. I'll delete these in a minute s to remove the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would supply it with `content` which is being passed in as the parameter `doc`:

```
def emails(doc):
    return findall('[\d]*@[\d]+', doc)
```

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) is of the following syntax: `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`

Also, your regex seems off. You are currently matching "numbers@numbers".

You probably want something like this:

```
def emails(doc):
    return findall('[\w.]+@[\w.]+', doc)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of Python's regular expressions, but \w typically matches little if any punctuation.  You probably want something like `[0-9A-Za-z._]+@[0-9A-Za-z._]+`.

Comment: It was definitely my regex! Thank you very much! @sshashank124